# How can I fix my problems with fonts in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

Ever since I reinstalled Ubuntu a few hours ago, I've experienced major visual artifacts with smaller font sizes in Firefox. The fonts end up looking like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdpiR.png]

Or even like this:

[image]

This only occurs in Firefox; other applications are unaffected. It also occurred on the LiveUSB I used for installation, making me suspect a hardware or driver issue. The output of lshw on my computer is here: http://pastebin.com/LnSt6veT.

Any idea what might be causing this, or how I can fix it?

... and "Use Google Chrome" is not a valid answer. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the Nouveau driver I was using; for whatever reason it wasn't rendering fonts correctly in FireFox. Switching to the proprietary Nvidia driver fixed it.

Comment: Seems to be weird.. Did you read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: No, but that's only about the NVidia driver, not about Nouveau. I've had similar weird problems with Nouveau before, though on other graphics cards.

Answer (score 3):

Removing 'msttcorefonts' might also fix it.

Comment: +1, this package is horrible, it makes the font ugly in firefox, I  always apt-pin it to prevent it from being installed.

Comment: That package is not installed. I installed it to test; having it installed changes nothing. :(

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have managed to solve your problem.
Still, if you're referring to a recent bug in Firefox that makes it 'disobey' the system-wide font settings in Ubuntu, this may help you out: http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8193420&postcount=11.

In short, the bug makes Firefox always render website fonts (and its chrome GUI fonts) anti-aliased (AA). The link above demonstrates how you can edit this and make Firefox always render all fonts crisp and pixel-ish, without any AA (this is especially good for webdesigners and people like me who hate anti-aliased fonts because of their visual artifacts).

The fix requires that you have root (a.k.a. admin) privileges (many tutorials on how to 'go root' are available online).

BTW, I'm a total newbie at Linux and Ubuntu is my fist Linux distro, which is why I approach such annoying 'bugs' from an end-user point of view (i.e. quick fixes). Despite this, Ubuntu 10.10 has been a mostly great experience for me and I wholeheartedly recommend it (as well as support all GNU/Linux distros and the open-source and free software movements). :)

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tweaking your font hinting settings in Preferences > Appearances?

Go to the Font tab and click Details...  See if a different setting improves the situation.

Comment: I tried that; but none of the settings help. Actually, FireFox doesn't seem to obey most of them. :(